NEST JS Typescript no overload matches this call
So i'm trying to save a data in the database but in mapping the values, I encounter an error of:
src/leads/leads.service.ts:34:10 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(value: { applicationRefId: string | SQL<unknown> | Placeholder<string, any>; }): MySqlInsertBase<MySqlTableWithColumns<{ name: "ServiceableLeads"; schema: undefined; columns: { leadId: MySqlColumn<{ name: "LeadId"; ... 12 more ...; generated: GeneratedColumnConfig<...>; }, object>; ... 26 more ...; updatedTimestamp: MySqlColumn<...>; }; dialect: "mysql"; }>, ... 4 more ..., never>', gave the following error.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'customerSegment' does not exist in type '{ applicationRefId: string | SQL<unknown> | Placeholder<string, any>; }'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(values: { applicationRefId: string | SQL<unknown> | Placeholder<string, any>; }[]): MySqlInsertBase<MySqlTableWithColumns<{ name: "ServiceableLeads"; schema: undefined; columns: { leadId: MySqlColumn<{ name: "LeadId"; ... 12 more ...; generated: GeneratedColumnConfig<...>; }, object>; ... 26 more ...; updatedTimestamp: MySqlColumn<...>; }; dialect: "mysql"; }>, ... 4 more ..., never>', gave the following error.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'applicationRefId' does not exist in type '{ applicationRefId: string | SQL<unknown> | Placeholder<string, any>; }[]'.

34         .values({

and here is the code:
Drizzle ORM generated schema:
export const serviceableLeads = mysqlTable(
  'ServiceableLeads',
  {
    leadId: int('LeadId').autoincrement(),
    applicationRefId: varchar('ApplicationRefId', { length: 255 }).notNull(),
    customerSegment: varchar('CustomerSegment', { length: 45 }),
    firstName: varchar('FirstName', { length: 128 }),
    lastName: varchar('LastName', { length: 128 }),
    mobileNumber: varchar('MobileNumber', { length: 45 }),
    emailAddress: varchar('EmailAddress', { length: 128 }),
    privacyNotice: tinyint('PrivacyNotice'),
    businessName: varchar('BusinessName', { length: 255 }),
    industryType: varchar('IndustryType', { length: 255 }),
    businessTin: varchar('BusinessTin', { length: 45 }),
    representativeFirstName: varchar('RepresentativeFirstName', {
      length: 128,
    }),
    representativeLastName: varchar('RepresentativeLastName', { length: 128 }),
    representativeGender: varchar('RepresentativeGender', { length: 45 }),
    representativeDepartment: varchar('RepresentativeDepartment', {
      length: 64,
    }),
    hasEmpOfGovtOrForeignEmbassy: tinyint('HasEmpOfGovtOrForeignEmbassy'),
    longitude: double('Longitude'),
    latitude: double('Latitude'),
    alternateContactNumber: varchar('AlternateContactNumber', { length: 128 }),
    landlineNumber: varchar('LandlineNumber', { length: 128 }),
    alternateEmailAddress: varchar('AlternateEmailAddress', { length: 128 }),
    planName: varchar('PlanName', { length: 128 }),
    step: int('Step'),
    customerBehavior: varchar('CustomerBehavior', { length: 128 }),
    agentCode: varchar('AgentCode', { length: 128 }),
    source: varchar('Source', { length: 128 }),
    createdTimestamp: datetime('CreatedTimestamp', { mode: 'string' }),
    updatedTimestamp: datetime('UpdatedTimestamp', { mode: 'string' }),
  },
  (table) => {
    return {
      serviceableLeadsLeadId: primaryKey({
        columns: [table.leadId],
        name: 'ServiceableLeads_LeadId',
      }),
      applicationRefIdUnique: unique('ApplicationRefId_UNIQUE').on(
        table.applicationRefId,
      ),
    };
  },
);

Service Layer Code:
import {
  Inject,
  Injectable,
  InternalServerErrorException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { WinstonLoggerService } from 'src/logger/logger.service';
import { ServiceableLeadsRequestDto } from './dto/request/serviceable-leads-request.dto';
import { MySql2Database } from 'drizzle-orm/mysql2';

import * as schema from 'src/backoffice/schema';
import { sql } from 'drizzle-orm';

@Injectable()
export class LeadsService {
  constructor(
    private readonly logger: WinstonLoggerService,
    @Inject('BACKOFFICE_DB')
    private readonly db: MySql2Database<typeof schema>,
  ) {}

  async saveLeads(
    serviceableLeadsRequestDto: ServiceableLeadsRequestDto,
  ): Promise<void> {
    const serviceableLeadData = await this.fetchServiceableLeadsData(
      serviceableLeadsRequestDto.applicationRefID,
    );

    if (!serviceableLeadData) {
      this.logger.log('SERVICEABLE LEAD DATA NOT FOUND CREATING A NEW ONE');
      console.log(schema.serviceableLeads);

      await this.db
        .insert(schema.serviceableLeads)
        .values({
          applicationRefId: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.applicationRefID,
          customerSegment: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.customerSegment,
          firstName: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.firstName,
          lastName: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.lastName,
          mobileNumber: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.mobileNumber,
          emailAddress: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.emailAddress,
          businessName: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.businessName,
          businessTin: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.businessTin,
          industryType: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.industryType,
          representativeFirstName:
            serviceableLeadsRequestDto.representativeFirstName,
          representativeLastName:
            serviceableLeadsRequestDto.representativeLastName,
          representativeDepartment:
            serviceableLeadsRequestDto.representativeDepartment,
          representativeGender: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.representativeGender,
          hasEmpOfGovtOrForeignEmbassy:
            serviceableLeadsRequestDto.hasEmpOfGovtOrForeignEmbassy ? 1 : 0,
          privacyNotice: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.privacyNotice ? 1 : 0,
          latitude: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.latitude,
          longitude: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.longitude,
          alternateEmailAddress:
            serviceableLeadsRequestDto.alternateEmailAddress,
          landlineNumber: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.landlineNumber,
          planName: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.planName,
          customerBehavior: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.customerBehavior,
          step: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.step,
          agentCode: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.agentCode,
          source: serviceableLeadsRequestDto.source,
          createdTimestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
          updatedTimestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        })
        .execute();
    }

    this.logger.log('SERVICEABLE LEAD DATA SUCCESFULLY SAVED');

    return null;
  }

  async fetchServiceableLeadsData(applicationRefID: string) {
    try {
      const result = await this.db
        .select()
        .from(schema.serviceableLeads)
        .where(
          sql`${schema.serviceableLeads.applicationRefId} = ${applicationRefID}`,
        )
        .execute();

      if (!result) {
        return null;
      }

      return result[0];
    } catch (error) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(error.message);
    }
  }
}

I expect to be able to map the values properly and save a data in the database as per checking thoroughly the attributes (casing, mapping, etc.) all seems to be good however it throws me that error
